# What is the proper config option to correctly word wrap in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Currently the output cells in my Jupyter Notebook version wraps in the middle of words splitting them incorrectly.  Below is a screenshot of the output where you can see the words service and installation are split instead of wrapping to the next line prior to the word.

[image]

Here is my `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` config file details.

```
{
    "MarkdownCell": 
    {
        "cm_config": 
        {
            "lineWrapping": true
        }
    },

    "CodeCell": 
    {
        "cm_config": 
        {
            "lineWrapping": true
        }
    },

    "Cell": 
    {
        "cm_config": 
        {
            "lineNumbers": false,
            "lineWrapping": true
        }
    },

    "codeCellConfig": {
        "lineWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
        "wordWrapColumn": 80
     }

}
```

What am I missing to have my output wrap properly?

Comment: Make sure your config is valid json (no trailing comma etc). You might also try enabling: `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`